# hector map static map

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, hector-slam, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, I'm new to the forum and to ROS.

I'm trying to use hector_slam without it updating the map. The reason is I have loaded a static map via map_server, the map loads correctly but only for a few frames, after which it is replaced by hector generated map.

I modified HectorMappingRos.cpp by switching p_use_static_map. Now no new map is generated (which is good), only laser scans are shown in navViz, but the static map is still removed after a few seconds after the static map is loaded and displayed.

Is there a way to make hector mapping to listen to map_server, or to connect to mapTopic from map_server or to make it not to replace the static map at all?

Thank you,

Octavio

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273305/hector-map-static-map/) by [opo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32233/opo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-10-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nrakoski3](https://answers.ros.org/users/47921/nrakoski3/) on 2019-10-25**:
Hello Octavio I am also trying to use hector_mapping with a static map for a school project. Do you have a link to your code or could you explain to me the changes you made in hector mapping?

When I broadcast my .tif map with the map_server the process dies. How did you feed hector_mapping the static map in the launch file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I figured it out. It was an issue with the yalm configuration file having too much offset for the center. A zoom out revealed the map and was able to fix the offset.

Thank you,

Octavio

---

Originally posted by [opo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32233/opo/) with karma: 16 on 2017-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0